# Counter increment until reaches 2

Tags: php

The following code will stop increment until it reaches 2:

```
$counter = 1;

if (isset($_POST["isPostBack"])) {

    $result = $dataobj->getProductsCart($_POST['productid'], $_SESSION["Username"]);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
         $dataobj->updateCartQty($_POST['productid'], $_SESSION["Username"], ++$counter);
    }
    else {
        $dataobj->insertIntoCart($_POST['productid'], $_SESSION["Username"], 1);
        $counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Do you know the reason please?

Comment: is there more code around this?

Comment: May be, because it increments only once?

Comment: how to increment more than once

Answer (score 1):

It will increment `$counter` to 2 when `isset($_POST["isPostBack"])` is true and when the number of rows returned from the query is > 0.

Since the counter starts at 1, that execution path increments it once, leaving it at 2.

Comment: how to increment more than once please

Comment: To increment it more than once, you would need the incrementing code to execute more than once. Loops are often used to execute a section of code more than 1 time.

Comment: why loop if i am getting only one product?

Comment: can you show me please f it's easy?